# Модификация алгоритма Bitap для текста, содержащего универсальный символ

Tags: c++, алгоритм, биоинформатика, нечеткий-поиск

Метод нечеткого поиска подстроки в тексте имеет следующую схему:

[image: Схема алгоритма Bitap]

Вот реализация его в части замен на C++ (взято отсюда: www.programmingalgorithms.com/algorithm/fuzzy-bitap-algorithm?lang=C%2B%2B )

```
static int SearchString(string text, string pattern, int k)
{
int result = -1;
int m = pattern.size();
unsigned long *R;
unsigned long patternMask[CHAR_MAX + 1];
int i, d;

if (pattern[0] == '\0') return 0;
if (m > 31) return -1; //Error: The pattern is too long!

R = new unsigned long[(k + 1) * sizeof *R];
for (i = 0; i <= k; ++i)
    R[i] = ~1;

for (i = 0; i <= CHAR_MAX; ++i)
    patternMask[i] = ~0;

for (i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    patternMask[pattern[i]] &= ~(1UL << i);

for (i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; ++i)
{
    unsigned long oldRd1 = R[0];

    R[0] |= patternMask[text[i]];
    R[0] <<= 1;

    for (d = 1; d <= k; ++d)
    {
        unsigned long tmp = R[d];

        R[d] = (oldRd1 & (R[d] | patternMask[text[i]])) << 1;
        oldRd1 = tmp;
    }

    if (0 == (R[k] & (1UL << m)))
    {
        result = (i - m) + 1;
        break;
    }
}

free(R);
return result;
}
```

Пример использования:  SearchString("This is my bubble gum", "gun",1) вернет индекс начала "gum".

---

Вопрос: можно ли, не особо усложняя код, ввести для текста text, в котором осуществляется поиск, зарезервированный символ, например "!", которому может соответствовать любой символ из подстроки pattern, т.е. чтобы SearchString("This is my !u!ble gum", "gun",1) возвращала индекс "!u!"?

Собственно, самому (чтобы не выглядеть лентяем) приходит в голову такая вставка в цикле **for (d = 1; d <= k; ++d)**:

```
if (text[d] == "!") R[d] = (oldRd1 & R[d]) << 1
else R[d] = (oldRd1 & (R[d] | patternMask[text[i]])) << 1;
```

Но, может, можно изящнее? :)