# Отловить ошибку в алгоритме нечеткого поиска Bitap

Tags: алгоритм, delphi, pascal, динамическое-программирование, биоинформатика

Реализовал (с подсказками, не бехз этого :)) алгоритм нечеткого поиска подстроки в строке по [уже бывшему тут вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/646056/):

```
function BitapSearchString(text, pattern:string; diff,index:integer):integer;
var
  m, i, d, old, tmp, tm:integer;
  R: array of integer;
  patternMask: array[0..127] of integer;
  ordpattern:array of integer;
begin
    m:= length(pattern);
    Result:=-1;
    if m = 0 then
       begin
        Result:=0;
        exit;
       end;
    if (m > 31) then
        exit;

    SetLength(R,diff+1);
    for i := 0 to diff do
       R[i]:= not 1;
    for i:=0 to 127 do
        patternMask[i] := not 0;
    for i := 0 to m-1 do
       patternMask[ord(pattern[i+1])]:=patternMask[ord(pattern[i+1])] and not (1 shl i);

    for I := index to length(text) do
      begin
        old:=R[0];
        R[0]:=R[0] or patternMask[ord(text[i])];
        R[0]:=R[0] shl 1;
        for d := 1 to diff do
          begin
            tmp:=R[d];
            if text[i] = 'N' then R[d]:=(old and tmp) shl 1
            else R[d]:=(old and (tmp or patternMask[ord(text[i])])) shl 1;
            old:=tmp;
          end;
        if (R[diff] and (1 shl m)) = 0  then
          begin
            Result:=(i-m)+1;
            break;
          end;
      end;
  SetLength(R,0);
end;
```

Всё хорошо, работает в 99% случаев, однако иногда возвращает позицию в строке не с начала, а с конца. При этом результат, формально, остаётся правильным, но сравниваются не начала строк, а концы Понять почему - не могу. Прекрасно понимаю, что искать чёрную кошку в тёмной комнате - чревато. Однако, сам не силён в динамическом программировании, поэтому прошу подсказки **КАК начать ловить ошибку?** Тупо сидеть и ждать брекпойнта - бесполезно: неоднократно пытался.

Comment: Вы бы написали с какими словами проблемы.

Comment: Попробовал погонять вашу функцию, проблем пока не нашёл...